# Inner table in pdatatable - columns not taking equal width

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have a pdatatable with an inner table inside the row expander template.
But the inner table columns are not taking equal width. The screenshot has been attached below.There are more columns to the right of the first column(Name) which is not visible unless I resize the columns.But you cant expect every user to do that.
[image]

Can someone please tell me why this is so.

template-->

```
    <p-dataTable [value]="tableData" [rows]="rows" [paginator]="paginate" [resizableColumns]="true" tableStyleClass="table-wrap" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]" expandableRows="{{setExpander}}">
    <p-column *ngIf="setExpander" expander="true" styleClass="expander-icon-col"></p-column>
    <div *ngFor="let col of tableOptions.columns">
            <p-column *ngIf="col.field" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [sortable]="col.sortable" [filter]="col.filter" [editable]="col.editable" [filterPlaceholder]="col.filterPlaceholder">
    </p-column>
    </div>
    <template let-col let-index="rowIndex" pTemplate="rowexpansion" *ngIf="setExpander">
            <p-dataTable [value]='subTableData[col[subTableOptions.mapperKey]]' [paginator]="paginate" [rows]='rows' [resizableColumns]="true" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]">
                <div *ngFor="let colum of subTableOptions.columns">
                    <p-column *ngIf="colum.field" [field]="colum.field" [header]="colum.header" [sortable]="colum.sortable" [filter]="colum.filter" [filterPlaceholder]="colum.filterPlaceholder"></p-column>

        </div>
    </p-dataTable>
    </template>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: where is the template code ?

Comment: now I have added

Comment: Can someone please help?

Comment: Will look into it tomorrow Ramya. Hectic work. Remind me in fb @ aravind2109

Comment: @Aravind Did you get a chance to look into this issue?

Comment: I still havnt got an ans for this. Can you upvote, once you come across this question so that I can get an ans at the earliest.

Comment: hey hi. I said you remind me I forgot. just seeing what is the actual problem

Comment: There are more columns to right of name in inner table, which is not seen.The columns are not taking equal widths in inner table.

Comment: are you there? Remya

Comment: Yes. I cant login to SO chat at the moment. Have you any clue as to what the issue might be?

Comment: can we move into discussion chat??

Comment: Ok cant really find out where the chat option is in this app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141613/discussion-between-aravind-and-remyaj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this. It was due to some css issue. Primng was adding a css table-layout:fixed to inner table , changing this to auto fixed the issue.